# WPF C# reducing render time, for mutli usercontrol layout

Tags: c#, wpf, app.xaml

Hello I have problem with my WPF page loading it took more than 2 seconds, my page contains 2 listview one listview contains ~70 items and second one contains ~355 items, of course everyone would say use virtualization and you done, yes it used but not on listview but on higher level, since my app use one scrollviever = one page method, I highly think due to this method virtualization does not work as expected since if it would work loading times be much better, one row took between 15-25ms to render

This is my problematic code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="app.OS.Tabs.Controls.SectionATabs"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:helpButton="clr-namespace:app.COMMON.USERCONTROLS.HelpButton"
         xmlns:Buttons="clr-namespace:app.COMMON.USERCONTROLS.Buttons"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="Auto"
         Width="Auto"
         MinHeight="120">
<VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" >
    <TextBlock MaxWidth="948" Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book." TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource GrayText}" Margin="0,15,0,7"/>
    <ListView x:Name="DataList"
                                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
                                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                    SelectionMode="Single" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemWithGridStandard}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}"
          >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRemover}" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Width="400">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel Height="47">
                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" ToolTip="{Binding Description,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}"  MaxWidth="360" Style="{StaticResource BlackText}" Height="21" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Description,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    <helpButton:HelpButton KeyToSearch="{Binding KeyToSearch,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}" SectionToUse="sectionA" HeaderButton="False" />
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GrayText}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Current: <Run Text="{Binding CurrentValue,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}"/><LineBreak/>Good Value:<Bold>0%</Bold></TextBlock>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="540">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Width="528">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Buttons:Buttons x:Name="DefaultValueButton" OnClick="DefaultValueButton_OnOnClick" ButtonContent="Default" ButtonData="{Binding Index,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}" DisabledBorderBrush="{StaticResource SeparatorColor}" DisabledBackgroundBrush="{StaticResource WhiteColor}" DisabledTextForegroundBrush="{StaticResource GrayForText}" ActiveBackgroundBrush="{StaticResource HeaderColor}" ActiveBorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" ActiveTextForegroundBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" IsActive="{Binding IsDefault,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource GrayText}">(<Run Text="{Binding DefaultValue,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}"></Run>)</TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Margin="9,0,0,0">
                                        <Buttons:Buttons x:Name="RecommendedValueButton" OnClick="RecommendedValueButton_Click"  ButtonContent="Recommended" ButtonData="{Binding Index,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}" DisabledBorderBrush="{StaticResource SeparatorColor}" DisabledBackgroundBrush="{StaticResource WhiteColor}" DisabledTextForegroundBrush="{StaticResource GrayForText}" ActiveBackgroundBrush="{StaticResource HddColor}" ActiveBorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" ActiveTextForegroundBrush="{StaticResource WhiteColor}" IsActive="{Binding IsRecommended,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource GrayText}">(<Run Text="{Binding RecommendedValue,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}"></Run>)</TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <Rectangle Width="1" Fill="{StaticResource SeparatorColor}" Height="24" Margin="16,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <Buttons:Buttons x:Name="EnableCustomValuesButton" OnClick="EnableCustomValuesButton_Click"  ButtonContent="Custom" ButtonData="{Binding Index,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}" DisabledBorderBrush="{StaticResource SeparatorColor}" DisabledBackgroundBrush="{StaticResource WhiteColor}" DisabledTextForegroundBrush="{StaticResource GrayForText}" ActiveBackgroundBrush="{StaticResource CpuColor}" ActiveBorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" ActiveTextForegroundBrush="{StaticResource WhiteColor}" IsActive="{Binding IsCustom,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsCustomEnabled,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                                            <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SeparatorColor}" Width="90" Margin="7,0">
                                                <Border.Clip>
                                                    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Rect="0 0, 90 25"/>
                                                </Border.Clip>
                                                <TextBox Width="86" Height="23"  x:Name="CustomValue" Text="{Binding CustomInputValue,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                            </Border>
                                            <Buttons:Buttons x:Name="CustomValueApply" OnClick="CustomValueApply_Click"  ButtonContent="Apply" ButtonData="{Binding Index,IsAsync=True,Mode=OneWay}" DisabledBorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" DisabledBackgroundBrush="{StaticResource WhiteColor}" DisabledTextForegroundBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</VirtualizingStackPanel>
```

This which may raise questions Buttons:Buttons is usercontrol inside it is border and inside border is textblock, helpButton:HelpButton is usercontrol inside it is border inside it is canvas with textblock and image(after some time image is disabled and on first time only image is shown only), headerremover sets GridViewColumnHeader visibility to collapsed, ListViewItemWithGridStandard is style which modify Control.Template adding inside Border and inside it adds GridViewRowPresenter, as you can see SectionATabs is tabcontrol > tabitem child, but tabcontrol is in page between page and tabcontrol is scrolviewer. page and scrollviewer has fixed height(maxheight also same) which is 501, also page is created way before user clicks for the first time, I think I told everything, now what can be done to reduce loading times? Thank you.

Comment: Remove the virtualisinstackpanel. Does your problem disappear?

Comment: Idea of virtualstackpanel was that there is user can see 5 rows of this listview and then another 65 is non visible thats why I though virtualstackpanel would resolve this problem

Comment: A listview has a virtualising stackpanel as it's itemspanel. Unless you're using an ancient obsolete version of the wpf framework.

Comment: From my point of view delete all of those `UC`s they are an overkill for what you need and use Grids instead. All of those buttons can use DataTemplate instead as well. Have you been coding in `WinForms` before?

Comment: @Andy as I said and you probably saw that I have disabled scrolbars from listview, since only scrolbar is in page section meaning that scrolviewer content heigh is fully dynamic, I'm using .Net fw 4.6, so it should mean that I'm using latest one, Xamimax  I didnt have chance to touch winforms, but trying understand your idea is that I need to remove UC and put outside datatemplate?

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. If you remove the outer virtualising stackpanel and make the listviews inside it virtualise. Does your problem then go away? Yes or no?

Comment: Yes, it much better, BUT it adds another scrollbar which my point is to remove. And be only on page scrollviever which can scroll up and down from this usercontrol content, meaning that listview has to show its all rows and virtualizingstackpanel should somehow solve slow loading, but it doesnt

Comment: It can only virtualise direct content. There is no virtualisation in your markup above.

Comment: Is there anything I could do to reduce render times without using listviews virtualisation?